# Cisco ASA: Allow established traffic back in

Tags: firewall, cisco, cisco-asa

I have a Cisco ASA 5505 (ver 8.2(2)) with two interfaces; inside (security level 100) and outside (security level 50).  There is one subnet on inside, 10.1.1.0/24.

There is no NAT for traffic moving from inside to outside; that is handled by an upstream router.

I want to configure the firewall so that any system on the inside interface can initiate a connection to the outside world and receive the return traffic but the outside world cannot initiate connections to the inside systems.  Letting the traffic out is easy:

```
access-list inside_in extended permit IP 10.1.1.0 255.255.255.0 any
```

but what do I need to configure on the ASA to let the responses back in without opening the firewall to all traffic?  normally this is handled by NAT, but in this case I do not want to use NAT.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Last time I checked, you don't need to define a rule when crossing from a high security zone (100) to a lower security zone, it's permitted by default.

That being said, you'll want to look at the [established](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/security/asa/asa82/command/reference/ef.html#wp1927618) documentation.  Also doesn't hurt to take a quick look at the [security-level](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/security/asa/asa82/command/reference/s1.html#wp1422126) docs either.

Comment: Perfect: the following three lines have everything we need working:

established tcp 0 0 
established udp 0 0 
access-list outside_in extended permit icmp any any echo-reply


The allow-inside-out rule is there due to force of habit, as well as my dislike of trusting default settings that don't get displayed in configs. :-)

Answer (score 1):

The ASA is stateful by default.  If you allow the traffic out (either by security-level processing or by ACL) it will automatically allow the return traffic back through.

I would be inclined to believe you are actually running into a **nat-control** issue.  Nat-control enforces the use of NAT, which is to say, if nat-control is enabled, any traffic traversing firewall interfaces MUST be NATed or it gets dropped.  In 8.2 code, **nat-control** is enabled by default.

Since you mention you are not doing NAT on your Firewall, you will also have to disable nat-control by using the command **no nat-control** from global configuration.  That, or configure NAT Exemptions to instruct your firewall to *not* NAT your traffic, while still satisfying nat-control.

To check if it is enabled: **show run nat-control**

Answer (score 0):

I don't have ASA experience but with Cisco IOS the way you allow traffic back in is with the `ip inspect` command and this falls under [Context Based Access Control (CBAC)](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/sw/secursw/ps1018/products_tech_note09186a0080094e8b.shtml). This enables a stateful firewall feature on the IOS and creates temporary holes in the firewall (ACL) to allow for related traffic.

Maybe it is the same of ASA?